# How to determine the probability for acceptance sampling

Tags: probability

I have a probability practice problem and the answer but I don't know how they arrived at the solution. Can someone help me with how to approach this? The answer is $0.225$.

"The manager of a small hardware store buys electric clocks in cartons of $12$ clocks each. To see whether each carton is acceptable, $3$ clocks are randomly selected and thoroughly tested. If all $3$ are of acceptable quality, then the carton of $12$ is accepted. Suppose in a certain carton, unknown to the hardware manager, only $8$ of the $12$ are of acceptable quality. What is the chance that the sampling scheme will inadvertently accept the carton?"

I believe that each clock selection is equally likely so each would have a probability of $\frac{1}{12}$. And each combination of selecting $3$ clocks would be $\frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{1}{12}$. I have tried building a Venn diagram but it seems there are so many combinations that it is confusing me. I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: You need to find the probability that all three items in the sample are among the eight clocks that are of acceptable quality.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to select 3 clocks of 12 clocks with acceptable quality. In each carton there are 8 acceptable clocks. The manager select the first acceptable clock with probability $\frac{8}{12}$. This is the fraction of number of acceptable clocks and  number of all clocks in the carton. After the first selection $7$ acceptable clocks and $11$ clocks in total remain in the carton. Thus the probability to select the second acceptable clock is  $\frac{8-1}{12-1}=\frac{7}{11}$.  Similar for selecting the third acceptable clock: $\frac{7-1}{11-1}=\frac{6}{10}$.

Let $C_i$ be the event that the manager select the i-th acceptable clock. Then it is asked for

$$P(C_1\cap C_2\cap C_2)=P(C_1)\cdot P(C_2|C_1)\cdot P(C_3|C_1\cap C_2)= \frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{11}\cdot \frac{6}{10}=\frac{14}{55}\approx 0.255$$

The notation with the events is not so important for calculating the result. I just post it for completeness. It seems that there is a small typo in your solution.